# Mixtilinears and Symmedians

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles, angle

[image]

(this is from EGMO)

Prove that angles ATK and LTI are equal.

The hint in the book was about symmedians. I am not sure how to prove that line segment AT is the T symmedian, angle chasing did not work, I tried proving $TM_c * M_cA = AM_b*TM_b$

Comment: There is a forum in AOPS , where each and every exercise is discussed 
https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c618937_euclidean_geometry_in_mathematical_olympiads 
Just shared it in case you didn't know about this ..

Answer (score 1):

$CLIT$ is cyclic as proven in the previous exercise hence $\angle LTI = \angle ICL = \angle M_{C}CA  = \angle ATM_{C} = \angle ATK$.

Or another solution from the hint, we have that $TA$ is the symmedian of $\triangle TKL$, hence the result.